# Rails: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Superclass expected, got Subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, has-many, type-mismatch

I am trying to create a class model for my application which has the following key features:

- Inheritance (the class `Place` acts as a superclass for `Farm` and `Depot`). I added the [gem multiple_table_inheritance](https://github.com/mhuggins/multiple_table_inheritance) to implement this.
- Relationship for a `Place` (can have many `places`)

I am using Rails 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.3.p194.

Here is a rough class model of what I am trying to implement.

[image: Class model]

You can find the relationship definition in the `Place` model:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_superclass
  attr_accessible :location, :name, :subtype

  has_many :place_connections, foreign_key: :place_a_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :places, through: :place_connections, source: :place_b
  has_many :reverse_place_connections, class_name: :PlaceConnection, \
            foreign_key: :place_b_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The `Farm` model can be seen in the following. The `Depot` model looks the same.

```
class Farm < ActiveRecord::Base
  inherits_from :place
end
```

However, when I check the relationship model in Rails console I experience the following:

```
> farm = Place.first
 => #<Farm place_id: 1, created_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:16", \
                        updated_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:16"> 
> depot = Place.last
 => #<Depot place_id: 6, created_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:44", \
                         updated_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:44"> 
> farm.places = [depot]
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Place(#42600420) expected, \ 
                                   got Depot(#42518820) ...
```

Can you tell whether I configured the relationship correctly? What am I doing wrong? Maybe I mixed up **singular** and **plural** names for the models and associations.

---

## Problem identified

I think we (a friend of mine and me) found out what the problem is:
Whenever the database already contains a relation of two `places` and you are trying to replace the pair of ids with the **exact same pair** the type mismatch error is raised. The error does not pop up if you replace the existing pair with **another pair**.

### Failing Example:

Before:

```
 PlaceConnection
-----------------
place_a | place_b
-----------------
    1        6
-----------------
```

Action:

```
> farm = Place.first
 => #<Farm place_id: 1, created_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:16", \
                        updated_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:16"> 
> depot = Place.last
 => #<Depot place_id: 6, created_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:44", \
                         updated_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:44"> 
> farm.places = [depot.place]
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Place(#42600420) expected, \ 
                                   got Depot(#42518820) ...
```

### Working Example:

Before:

```
 PlaceConnection
-----------------
place_a | place_b
-----------------
    3        2
-----------------
```

Action:

```
> farm = Place.first
 => #<Farm place_id: 1, created_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:16", \
                        updated_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:16"> 
> depot = Place.last
 => #<Depot place_id: 6, created_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:44", \
                         updated_at: "2013-02-08 12:19:44"> 
> farm.places = [depot.place]
=> [#<Place id: 6, name: "Some depot", location: "Somewhere", subtype: "Depot", \
   created_at: "2013-02-09 12:51:01", updated_at: "2013-02-09 12:51:01">]
```

## Please note

Another thing we realized is that it is and was all the time possible to extend the array of relations as follows: `farm.places << depot.place`. This is probably what we want to use anyways. Nevertheless, the assignment problem might be a bug?!

Answer (score 1):

On the last line, try replacing this:

```
farm.places = [depot]
```

with this:

```
farm.places = [depot.place]
```

The `.place` method should return the superclass instance of `Place`, (which is technically what `PlaceConnection` is referencing) instead of the subclass instance of `Depot`.

Comment: Sounds great, though I have to admit that it results in the **same error message** as before.

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you output `depot.place.inspect` or `depot.place.class`?

Comment: It outputs the hash of the `Place` instance for `.inspect` and the `Place` properties for `.class`.

Comment: So `depot.place` sounds like it is working properly, returning the `Place` instance as expected.  Given that, I can't imagine why the new line wouldn't work.  What happens if you try doing this instead?  `farm.places = [Place.new]`?  Or if that doesn't work, try replacing `farm.places` with `farm.depot.places`.  I'm curious to see where the logic is failing.

Comment: The assignment `farm.places = [Place.new]` executes **without errors**. Your second test does not make sense to me; the `farm` instance does not expose an accessor called `depot`. Was this a typo? I guess you meant `farm.place.places = [Place.new]` which **executes successfully**, too.

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant to say `farm.place.places`, not `farm.depot.places`.  Glad you figured out what I meant.  It sounds like there may be a bug that needs to be looked into, but this might be (hopefully) a viable workaround in the meantime.  Can I ask what version of Rails you're using?  I believe 3.2.11 introduced some issues with association assignment, and this might relate to it, but perhaps not.

Comment: Yes. I am using Rails 3.2.11. What are you suggesting?

Comment: I changed the Rails version to 3.2.7 and 3.2.9 and repeated the procedure. Same result.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  I'll try to reproduce and update the gem if necessary.